# How to login as a different user in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, user-accounts

I'm currently logged in as a normal user in OS X.

I'd like to start a terminal session and login as user `foo`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `su - foo`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried using `su - foo`?

**Update** based on the comments:

The empty `-` tells `su` to make a full login. That means (from the man page),

> The environment is discarded except for HOME, SHELL, PATH, TERM, and USER.  HOME and SHELL are modified as above.  USER is set to the target login.  PATH is set to ``/bin:/usr/bin''.  TERM is imported from your current environment.  The invoked shell is the target login's, and su will change directory to the target login's home directory.

So, if you need any other environment variables, such as `DISPLAY` to open programs that use the window server, you have to omit the empty `-`.

Comment: The login works fine but  I tried `mate myfile` and I'm getting a "failed to connect to WindowServer" error. This isn't a critical fix, but it would be great to get this working.

Comment: @macek: That's because there's no Window Server (aqua) attached to the terminal. If the user is currently logged on in the graphic environment, try `open -a TextMate myfile`.

Comment: @macek: I'm not sure, but maybe `su foo` could do it. Omitting the `-` keeps the values environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for the help. @kraftan, perhaps update the answer to include both with a brief explanation. :)

Comment: @Georg, that didn't seem to work.

Comment: May be obvious to everyone else, but I needed to run it as sudo: `sudo su - foo`

Answer (score 6):

On MacOS X use `login`

$ `login`

login: `your username`

password: `your password`

Last login: Day Month Date HH:MM:SS on ttys000

$ `whoami`

your username

I was having issues running `nano` after using `su - admin`
to edit a `.bashrc` file. When adjusting the window size the text would become garbled. The answer I found below explains why and led me in the correct direction.

"The terminal emulator will send a Window Change signal (SIGWINCH) to the shell that was started along with the terminal emulator. The shell is supposed to pass it on to its children - but when you've transitioned to another user account (using su or otherwise), it won't be able to signal that shell because it's running as a different user. So the su'd shell and any programs run from it will keep using the old window size, oblivious to the fact that the real window size has changed." --[telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577070/400324)

Answer (score -2):

I have tried `su` many times but I found `sudo` to be easier. You can try

```
sudo -u <username>
```

Comment: My sudo doesn't seem to have a `-u` option

Comment: This is dangerous and not the same as logging in to a user with admin privileges. When you are running as sudo, you are running in elevated privileges. If you perform certain kinds of installs, such as with homebrew, the elevated user privileges will stick: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/permission-problems/3011/19.